# Three.js - accessing a child object in a scene

Tags: javascript, object, three.js, blender

I'm trying to access the child object `sole` in a scene. I am able to access the var `sole` inside the loader function using `obj`, but I need to access it from outside the loader function.

[Here's the working code](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/2/) and 
[here's the json model file](http://deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/2/models/shoe4.json).

I can access it from inside the loader, like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();  
loader.load("models/shoe4.json", function (obj) {
    scene.add (obj);
    scene.rotation.y = Math.PI/1;
    scene.position.y = -5;
    scene.position.z = -24;

    var sole = obj.getObjectByName( "sole", true );
    sole.position.y = -5;

});
```

But I need to do something like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();  
loader.load("models/shoe4.json", function (obj) {
    scene.add (obj);
    scene.rotation.y = Math.PI/1;
    scene.position.y = -5;
    scene.position.z = -24;     
});

var sole = obj.getObjectByName( "sole", true );
sole.position.y = -5;
```

Basically I need to put it it's own function for later use.

I also tried

```
var sole = scene.getObjectByName( "sole", true );
sole.position.y = -5;
```

Which gave me the error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '`getObjectByName`' of undefined

How do I access the object `sole` from anywhere? Simply declaring `var obj,` is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to _define_ `sole` outside the loader function, but _assign_ it inside the loader function?

Comment: Yes. I have a bunch of vars on the first line `var sole, obj`etc,  but then if I try to access `sole = obj.getObjectByName( "sole", true );` from outside the loader function I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getObjectByName' of undefined`. Seems strange, one would think this should work perfectly.

Comment: @AgenZebra No, try to **assign** `sole` _inside_ the loader function, not outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you declare `sole` outside the scope of the lambda function, like this:

```
var sole = null;
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();  
loader.load("models/shoe4.json", function (obj) {
    scene.add (obj);
    scene.rotation.y = Math.PI/1;
    scene.position.y = -5;
    scene.position.z = -24;

    sole = obj.getObjectByName( "sole", true );
    sole.position.y = -5;

});

// this will FAIL because sole is undefined when this line of code executes
sole.position.x = 5;
```

Second, the program must not access `sole` until *after* the lambda function is actually executed. If you're not familiar with the asynchronous (or event-driven)  programming model, then you should do a little reading about it:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700330.aspx