# Three js get child object from imported model

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I imported a 3D model which has a few child objects and now I would like to get a specific child mesh.

When I use `.getObjectByName("Cylinder", true)` I always get `undefined` back, although the model has a child object with the specifed name:

[image]

Is there a way to get the child object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A piece of code would be useful, but there is a pretty common [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900485/three-js-accessing-a-child-object-in-a-scene) happening when You are trying to access the model properties before it actually loads.

Until the model actually loads, You can't access it's properties.

I would suggest listening for the `model-loaded` event, the [gltf-model](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/gltf-model.html), and the [obj-model](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/obj-model.html). It should work like this:

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent("modelhandler", {
  init:function() {
     this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", (e)=> 
     let child = obj.getObjectByName( "Cylinder", true );
     console.log(child);
   });
}
</script>

<a-entity gltf-model="url(/path/to/model.gltf)" modelhandler></a-entity>
```

---

If that won't work, You can also try setting a timeout for 5 seconds ( 99% the cube, and a sphere will load within 5 secs), and then trying to grab the child objects. Try putting something like this in the component:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  let child = obj.getObjectByName( "Cylinder", true );
  console.log(child);
}, 5000});
```

Otherwise, at least You'll know the issue isn't about the loading.

Comment: Waiting until the model is loaded fixed it! Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @JesterWest I had the same problems when i started playing with models in aframe / three :) Glad i could help !

Comment: or add a manager to the loader to keep track: `const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();const loader = new Rhino3dmLoader(manager);` makes it available to use a method with a callback if obj is loaded